# Chrome sometimes not requesting CSS pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

This is an ASPX page and rarely the stylesheets do not load.  No Request either.  I can look at the network log in chromes debug and see that it didnt request it or load it from cache.  Everything else, img , js, whatever all loads without problem.  The only thing that this site does that I have never done before is load a stylesheet via javascript and that will request and work every time.   There is also an Iframe in the page and that css always works as well.   It feels like a 1 in 10 chance for this to happen, but its random.   I cant remember if it happens when i run it locally or not, but it will happen on the 3 different IIS servers.   In the sources of the Chrome DevTools it shows the file in there as well.  Is this a bug in chrome or something?   Is it a weird thing with closing tag in the links?   Has anyone seen this before?

```
<head>
....
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css?v=@Model.buildTag" />
    <link href="~/lib/tabulator/css/tabulator.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link id="glcss" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/empty.css">
</head>
```

This JS code runs mid way trough the initial js load of the page before doc render and it sets a stylesheet to the page.   Not sure if this would cause chrome to randomly abandon the other css documents.  This css always works.

```
 var stylesheetPath = _pth + "/css/custom_gl_theme_" + dd.value + ".min.css?v=" + _v;

    $('link[id="glcss"]').attr('href', stylesheetPath);
    this.value = dd.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know the cause, but this is the solution we had put in place.   Basically, once the page loads, we check to see if those css files loaded properly, and if not, reset the url and it would force the pull.

```
$(window).on('load', function (e) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
for (var i = 0, linkLen = links.length; i < linkLen; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        if ((link.id == "") && (link.type == "text/css")) {
            var cssHref = link.href;
            link.href = cssHref;
        }
    }
});
```